# After Effects & Media Encoder different resolution clips with same content export similar size using same settings

Tags: after-effects, export, adobe-media-encoder

this is driving me mad, I have one clip at 4K 3840x2160 and I export it via After Effects as h264, Constant Bitrate 16 and let's say it's 56 MBs. If I resize it in After Effects export/render window to 1080p (1920x1080) I get a 1080p file that is something like 54MBs. I thought it was weird so I made a duplicate comp, changed its resolution to 1080p, resized everything in there with a null, exported it with same settings h264 CBR16 and now its size is something like 36MBs. I thought it was a bug in the resize when exporting and from then on kept duplicating all comps, resizing them down to 1080p and exporting separately. But I now found out that the problem returned (AE v.23.4.0 Build 53) and even with the internally resized comps I still get an exported mp4 size close to 4K resolution even when the comp has 1080p natively. The only way to bring size down is to lower the CBR rate to, say, 10. Why is this happening? Should a clip with half resolution than an other 4K clip with same content have 95% its size? Am I doing something wrong?